# How to enhance text with thesaurus in machine learning clustering/classification

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, python, text-mining

Sorry if this is not a relevant question, but my (almost-zero) knowledge does not even help me to find the answer properly.

This is the problem: I have a lot of text to cluster (or classify), but after stopword removing, stemming, lemmatisation (and so on), I would like to enhance my data with a thesaurus.

That way I can, for example, calculate TF-IDF of similar terms together, more than just the words per se.

I have read some scientific papers and I know there are some tools. But my question is more about some python (SciPy), R or even java example to include this enhancement step before execute some ML algorithm.